# marginnote problem with word wrap - scrbook

Tags: marginnote, scrbook

## Problem with marginnote

### Programcode

```
\documentclass[%
paper=a4,% 
fontsize=12pt,%
twoside=true,%
DIV=classic,%
headings=openany,% 
headings=small,% 
version=last,%
titlepage=true,%
parskip=half+,%
headsepline=true,%
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[noadjust]{marginnote}

\renewcommand{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\mn}[1]{\marginnote{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[2]\mn{Geschäftsprozesstyp}
\blindtext[2]

\pagebreak

\blindtext[1]\mn{Geschäftsprozesstyp}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

The problem is that the marginnote-package wraps words. On odd pages the word wraps and on even pages i don't want to have the word wrap.

Marginnotes on even and odd pages shouldn't wrap expect they are too long.

[image: e.g. Geschäftsprozesstyp just break in line]

I really need help to solve this problem.

Comment: that's odd, the word actually fits as you see if you use `\blindtext[2]\mn{Geschäftsprozesstyp  a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a
}` the note must have some strange para parameters set....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the note is set with

```
> 139.40363pt plus 1.0fil.
<argument> ...he \rightskip \showthe \parfillskip 
                                                  \showthe \hsize \endgraf \...
l.35 \blindtext
               [2]
? 
> 89.62619pt.
<argument> ...howthe \parfillskip \showthe \hsize
```

which makes no sense, it is saying the white space at the end of the last line must be longer than the width of the note.

```
\mn{\parfillskip=\fill
Geschäftsprozesstyp 
}
```

gives a more reasonable output.

Presumably this is the global option

```
parskip=half+,%
```

which has set parfillskip half the textwidth which is not being locally reset within the notes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried to change the option to : parskip=half-,%.